# PHP Fatal error: Class not found but included

Tags: php, class

html/app/RandomCode.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use \Carbon\Carbon;


class RandomCode
{
    public function random_str($length, $keyspace)
    {
        $str = '';
        $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

html/public/index.php

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../app/RandomCode.php');
$code = new RandomCode();
$code->random_str(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

I think it's all correct but i receive this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RandomCode' not found in /var/www/html/public/index.php on line 27`

I've tried with `var_dump(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../app/RandomCode.php'));` and i received `true`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: most likely you're not in the same namespace, so do: `$code = new App\RandomCode();` - Or did you set a namespace in index.php?

Comment: `Call to undefined function App\\random_int() in /var/www/ts3bot/app/RandomCode.php on line 15` with your tip

Comment: where is this function `random_int()` defined? Is this your class?

Comment: [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) was introduced in php7, I'm guessing you're using php5, you could use [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) instead

Comment: ...just found out about `random_int()` beeing a native php function.. oops

Comment: in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) you'll find a backporting-function for older php versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `random_int` function in PHP 5.X without the libraries required for that function. I've resolved using https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/releases